# Order Map Interface by value

Tags: java

This is the code that I have:

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(23,"Nitin");
map.put(45,"Kapil");
map.put(20, "Sam");
map.put(18,"Adam");
for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(m.getValue()+":"+m.getValue());
}
```

But I cannot possible order the data, I need to sort this hash map by value (Name).

Input: `Map<Age,Name>`

```
23, Nitin
45, Kapil
20, Sam
18, Adam
```

Output:

```
18, Adam
45, Kapil
23, Nitin
20, Sam
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Please check again refresh i put my code

Comment: You're trying to print based on some kind of sorting order?

Comment: this should be sorted asc by name

Comment: What output do you want? Also, what do the numbers represent? Since you want an ordering, you should use a `List` instead of a `Map`. You can do this if you create a class to hold the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use Java Streams to do this and sort the map my value:

```
Map<Integer, String> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (s1, s2) -> s1, LinkedHashMap::new));

sorted.forEach((i, s) -> System.out.println(i + ": " + s));
```

A [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will preserve the order in which the keys are added into the map.

The result would be this:

```
18: Adam
45: Kapil
23: Nitin
20: Sam
```

If you want to reverse the order of the values you can use `Comparator.reversed()`:

```
Map<Integer, String> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, String>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (s1, s2) -> s1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Thanks this is the solution Samuel